# Как сделать корректное отображение ссылки в телеграмм?

Tags: html, wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так что бы в телеграмме при отправке ссылки показывалась картинка и описание.в вайбере все нормально работает. сейчас использую такие настройки:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="Оптимизация Гугл Рекламы">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Рекламное агентство AVB GROUP">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://гугл-реклама.site/">
  <meta property="og:description" content="AVB GROUP - оперативно результативно качественно">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://гугл-реклама.site/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/favicon.png">
```

На других сайтах делаю все по аналогии и все работает как нужно, а тут вот проблемка. подскажите в какую хоть сторону копать? заранее большое спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Просто отправить ссылку как текст(как обычное текстовое сообщение) не работает уже? =)

Comment: так я тоже пробовал. не работает

Answer (score 0):

для решение проблемы нужно обновить данные в телеграмме. 
В Телеграме существует специальный бот — @Webpagebot, с помощью которого можно обновить кеш предпросмотра через интерфейс бота. Для этого нужно использовать команду /updatepreview, а потом прислать боту до 10 ссылок, предпросмотр которых в Телеграме вы хотите обновить.

Comment: Забавно, но вот в вопросе мне кажется вы слукавили, а именно о том что всё отображается, но данные устарели =)